# VBS Script error in SAP GUI control could not be found by id

Tags: vbscript, sap-gui

apologies for the n00b question, but I have a VBScript that I generated with SAP GUI.  This script works just fine.  I modified the same script by adding lines (basically just copy/paste and modify field numbers) and I am getting an the error which I will describe below.

The redacted WORKING VBScript is below:

http://pastebin.com/iv9AZQkp

The NON-working VBScript is below:

http://pastebin.com/zFBJMdKU

When I run the "non-working" script, it executes up to line 33, then errors when executing line 34 to the end.  I receive an error at SAP Frontend Server:

> The control could not be found by id

Does the code in the second VBScript look wrong in any way?  I don't understand why the first example works and the second does not.

Thank you in advance.

Steve

Working Script, Lines 31-48:

```
31 session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
32 session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
33 session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
34 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,0]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-TP-HA2-R"  
35 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,1]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-TP-HA2-R"  
36 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,2]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-TP-HA2-R"  
37 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,3]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-TP-HA2-R"  
38 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,4]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-URL2-HA2-R"
39 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,5]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-URL2-HA2-R"
40 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,0]").text = "1"
41 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,1]").text = "1"
42 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,2]").text = "1"
43 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,3]").text = "1"
44 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,4]").text = "1"
45 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,5]").text = "1"
46 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,2]").setFocus
47 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,2]").caretPosition = 19
48 session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

Non-working script, Lines 31-64:

```
31 session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
32 session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
33 session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
34 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,0]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-TP-HA2-R"  
35 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,1]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-TP-HA2-R"  
36 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,2]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-TP-HA2-R"  
37 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,3]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-TP-HA2-R"  
38 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,4]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-URL2-HA2-R"    
39 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,5]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-URL2-HA2-R"    
40 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,6]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-URL2-HA2-R"    
41 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,7]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-URL2-HA2-R"    
42 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,8]").text = "PAN-PA-500-TP-HA2-R"       
43 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,9]").text = "PAN-PA-500-TP-HA2-R"       
44 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,10]").text = "PAN-PA-500-TP-HA2-R"      
45 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,11]").text = "PAN-PA-500-TP-HA2-R"      
46 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,12]").text = "PAN-PA-500-TP-HA2-R"      
47 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,13]").text = "PAN-PA-500-TP-HA2-R"      
48 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,0 ]").text = "1"
49 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,1 ]").text = "1"
50 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,2 ]").text = "1"
51 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,3 ]").text = "1"
52 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,4 ]").text = "1"
53 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,5 ]").text = "1"
54 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,6 ]").text = "1"
55 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,7 ]").text = "1"
56 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,8 ]").text = "1"
57 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,9 ]").text = "1"
58 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,10]").text = "1"
59 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,11]").text = "1"
60 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,12]").text = "1"
61 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,13]").text = "1"
62 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,2]").setFocus
63 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,2]").caretPosition = 19
64 session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

Comment: Please put an excerpt of the relevant code in the body of your question.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the space before the closing bracket: `[1,0]` instead of `[1,0 ]`?

Comment: Good catch - I got rid of that space, this time lines 31-47 executed, but I received the same error of "The control could not be found by id-" at line 48.  Lines 31-47 are a product, and 48-60 are the corresponding quantities.  The product was inputted into SAP but the QTY was skipped b/c of error.  I was under the impression that VBscript disregarded spaces?  I might be wrong about that though.

Comment: I modified the code above to reflect the suggested changes that I re-ran, with the same error pointed out in my post above.

Comment: ...and did you forget to remove the very same space in lines 48ff in this question only or also in your code?

Comment: Can someone explain why someone would vote down this question?  I think it's perfectly valid, and a valid answer was provided...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out the issue - It is not a syntax error, but in case anyone else encountering issues with adding multiple lines in SAP ECC 6.0, SAP only allows to fire a max of 10 SKUs at a time, if the number of lines exceed [1,9], you must start the code again at 1,1 after firing the first 10.  My problem was that I had [1,10] through [1,13] when SAP won't allow [1,10] and above. Code is below:

```
31 session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
32 session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
33 session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
34 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,0]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-TP-HA2-R"  
35 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,1]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-TP-HA2-R"  
36 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,2]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-TP-HA2-R"  
37 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,3]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-TP-HA2-R"  
38 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,4]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-URL2-HA2-R"    
39 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,5]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-URL2-HA2-R"    
40 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,6]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-URL2-HA2-R"    
41 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,7]").text = "PAN-PA-2050-URL2-HA2-R"    
42 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,8]").text = "PAN-PA-500-TP-HA2-R"       
43 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,9]").text = "PAN-PA-500-TP-HA2-R"       
44 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,0]").text = "1"
45 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,1]").text = "1"
46 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,2]").text = "1"
47 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,3]").text = "1"
48 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,4]").text = "1"
49 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,5]").text = "1"
50 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,6]").text = "1"
51 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,7]").text = "1"
52 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,8]").text = "1"
53 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,9]").text = "1"
54 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,9]").setFocus
55 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,9]").caretPosition = 19
56 session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
57 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,0]").text = "PAN-PA-500-TP-HA2-R"       
58 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,1]").text = "PAN-PA-500-TP-HA2-R"       
59 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,2]").text = "PAN-PA-500-TP-HA2-R"       
60 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,3]").text = "PAN-PA-500-TP-HA2-R"       
61 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,0]").text = "1"
62 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,1]").text = "1"
63 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,2]").text = "1"
64 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,3]").text = "1"
65 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,2]").setFocus
66 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4411/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4912/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_ANGEBOT/txtRV45A-KWMENG[2,2]").caretPosition = 19
 67 session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

Thanks everyone for your input!  I'll leave this here for other's reference in case a similar issue is encountered.  -Steve

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space before the closing bracket: `[1,0]` instead of `[1,0 ]` throughout the **entire** edited code. Code alignment is certainly desirable, but only if it is supported by the language...